# How to package multiple external WebVTT tracks with HLS in Wowza

Tags: video-streaming, wowza, http-live-streaming, subtitle, video-on-demand

I am using wowza 4.5.0 build18676 version. Recently I am experimenting with multi-track support in wowza VOD streaming. Here are the set of files I have:

**sample.mp4** - 1 video track, 2 audio tracks(English, French).
**sample_english.vtt** - WebVTT subtitle file 
**sample_french.vtt** - WebVTT subtitle file

I would like to know the SMIL configuration for the following scenarios:

Streaming multilingual external VTT subtitle files along with sample.mp4 using HLS streaming protocol in wowza.

For example: I want to do HLS streaming of sample.mp4 and along with it I want to include **sample_english.vtt** and **sample_french.vtt** tracks.

I am looking for SMIL file configuration and any wowza server configuration for the above mentioned scenarios. Hope someone would have come across similar scenario. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Multi webVTT tracks are currently not supported in Wowza. You will need to use TTML sidecar caption files that do support multi-language, which you can then use in a single `<textstream>` in your SMIL file.

```
        <textstream src="multi.ttml" system-language="eng">
            <param name="isWowzaCaptionStream" value="true"/>
        </textstream>
```

SMIL files in Wowza can only have a single textstream parameter.